# In Internet Explorer, swf plays using object tag without audio

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio

I'm using object tag to play an SWF video. Both audio and video is working fine in Firefox and chrome and other browsers. But in Internet Explorer, Only video is working, the audio is not playing.

CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
   <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

<object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E- AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="780" height="390"> 
<param name="movie" value="../video/Video-3.swf" /> 
<!--[if !IE]>--> 
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../video/Video-3.swf" width="780" height="390"> 
<!--<![endif]--> <p>Alternative content</p> <!--[if !IE]>--> 
</object> <!--<![endif]--> 
</object>


</body></html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a jsFiddle, or the .swf you're using. We need more info, as this is pretty broad based on what we know